# Forwarding query string's parameters to webservice with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have the following not-so-restful API that I have to map with Angular's $resource:

```
GET /api/posts/:id
GET /api/list_posts/:kind
```

where the 2nd route returns every posts matching `:kind`.

Client-side, with AngularJS, I want to use these more conventional routes:

```
index.html#/posts/:id
index.html#/posts?kind=...
```

How can I define a $resource where `kind` is forwarded to the webservice?

I've tried the following but, alas, Angular doesn't understand what I mean by `:kind`:

```
appServices.factory('Post', ['$resource',
  function ($resource) {
    return $resource('/api/posts/:id', {}, {
      query: {url: '/api/list_posts/:kind'}
    });
  }])
```

EDIT: Example

If I have `index.html#/posts?kind=42` in my address bar, then the API should be queried this way: `/api/list_posts/42`.

If I have `index.html#/posts/42` in my address bar, then the API should be queried that way: `/api/posts/42`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to match url configuration with parameter in the options you pass:

```
return $resource('/api/posts/:id', { id: '@id' }, {
    query: { url: '/api/list_posts/:kind', params: { kind: '@kind' } }
});
```

Now $resource will look for `id` and `kind` values in the parameters you pass to it:

```
Post.get({ id: 42 });
Post.query({ kind: 'any' });
```